# Active Admin sort by 2nd level Association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations, activeadmin, associated-sorting

I have three Models. Both `makes` and `models` table have `name` column inside.

```
class Review < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :model
end

class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :make
    has_many :reviews
end

class Make < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :models
end
```

In Active Admin on Index Page I want to sort reviews by make and model.
I figured out how to sort it by model, because it has key the `reviews` table.
Tried a lot of things. Nothing works to sort by make name. I was able to list though.

```
ActiveAdmin.register Review do
    column "Model", sortable: 'model_id' do |p|
        p.model.name
    end
    column "Make", sortable: 'make_id' do |review|
        review.model.make.name
    end
end
```

Only sorting by model name works. I think if I add `make_id` to `Reviews` it will be working, but it seems redundant, cause a chain like `review.model.make` perfectly works

Answer (score 0):

Let's say a `review` is a score between 1 and 5.
You will have to compute the average value for each  `make`.

To compute an average value for a `make`, do:

```
reviews_sum = 0
total_reviews = 0

make.models.each do |model|
  model.reviews.each do |review|
    reviews_sum += review
    total_reviews += 1
  end
end
```

Then:

```
average_review = reviews_sum /  total_reviews.to_f # I am using to_f to convert total_reviews from integer to float. This way you can have a float result.
```

I advice you to create an `make_average_review(make_id, average_review)`
This way you can store/update your average review for every `make` and then sort by `make`

Comment: my question is related to Active Admin. I dont think this solution will work.

Comment: Keep in mind you can define `controllers` in `activeadmin`.